# Plotting heatmap by coordinates python

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I have an array of X locations and array of Y location, I create a table that holds coordinates of points and then I take the x of the points and the y.

And I want to create a heat map that shows areas that are warmer if they have more points in that area and areas that colder if they have less points in that area.
The heat map that I created shows the reverse of the wanted result, the colorbar is meant to be reversed but some how, I think it is showing the colors in the map by the distance of (0,0) and not be density.

I have used np.histogram2d.

Here you can see that the red area is 20 in the colorbar, but that doesn't make sense because this is the red area and meant to be more valuable, There is no way that the red area is around 20 and the blue is 120. maybe it represents the distance from (0,0)?!

[image]

Here I tried to play with the clim but the colors where reversed
[image]

And when I reversed the color, the values of the colorbar didn't change, but the colors did change
[image]

Comment: Without reproducible code and test data, your question looks extremely hard to answer. Now it is just a guessing game with too much missing information.

Comment: You might try seaborn, e.g. `sns.histplot(x=xs, y=ys, cmap='turbo', cbar=True)`. Or `sns.kdeplot(...)`